# How to access azure service bus message properties in Azure function 2

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Using azure functions version 1 it was possible to accept a message as BrokeredMessage.

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("MySServiceBus", "MySubscriptionName", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "MyConnectionString")]BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
```

And then retrieve the properties using code similar to this:

```
var MyProperty = message.Properties["MyMessageProperty"] as string
```

Using version 2.0 of the function SDK I can't cast the incoming object to a BrokeredMessage without getting a deserialization error message

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage. The input source is
>   not correctly formatted. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: The
>   input source is not correctly formatted.

Is it possible to get the message properties using functions 2.0

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - we're updating our docs on service bus bindings to reflect this change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 2.0 of runtime switched to the [new Service Bus client library based on .NET Standard](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet).

`BrokeredMessage` class is not part of that library, instead it has `Message` class with comparable functionality but different API.

You should be able to bind your input parameter to this class and then access custom properties via `Message.UserProperties` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I think the documentation will catch up soon.  To be fair 2.0 is still preview

Comment: can we use  `IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage>` when doing an output binding to servicebus in order to be able to add custom properties to the message?

Answer (score 5):

In the new world (azure functions .net5) you can no longer use brokered messages. The new libraries do not cater for it.

Function app declaration is no longer `[FunctionName=]` but `[Function=`
You can no longer receive `Message` or byte, but only a string.

Example:

```
 [Function("TestFA")]
 public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(topicName, subscriberName, Connection = ???)] string messageText, string id,  FunctionContext executionContext)
```

the magic is now in FunctionContext executionContext
you can get properties from this
e.g

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> props = executionContext.BindingContext.BindingData.Where(x => x.Key == "UserProperties").FirstOrDefault();
```